# iOS: Capture FRONT Camera with Overlay View with Video Background

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, overlay

I'm new to the community =)

My question...

Is it possible to have an overlay screen of the front camera while having a full screen video background. Sorry if it sounds a bit confusing, it might be easier if you see the mock-up at this link.

Mock-up: [Mock-up Link](http://www.boxhippo.com/stackexchange.png)

Building for the iPhone using either Obj C or Xcode.

Any reference or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Robert